Find solutions for equation $x^y \cdot y^x = z^z$
In one of the local magazines I have found a next question:
Find all integer solutions for equation:
$x^y  y^x = z^z$
where $x,y,z>1$
I have started by writing code to verify if such solution exist and got next answers:
    x      y       z
    2      4       4
    9     27      27
   64    256     256
  625   3125    3125
 7776  46656   46656

    2     16       8
   18    144     108 
   27     36      54
20736  46656   62208

It's very easy to explain how we got the first part of this table. All triples in form $(k^{k-1}, k^k, k^k)$ are going to satisfy equation. Proof:
$({k^{k-1}})^{k^k} ({k^k})^{k^{k-1}}=({k^k})^{k^k}$
$k^{(k-1)k^k} k^{k k^{(k-1)}}=k^{k{k^k}}$
$k^{(k-1)k^k + k k^{(k-1)}}=k^{k{k^k}}$
$ (k-1)k^k + k k^{(k-1)} = kk^k$
$ kk^k - k^k + k^k = kk^k $
$ kk^k = kk^k $
But I don't have any idea how to find all other solutions and prove their existence.

Interestingly, $\mathrm{lcm}(27,36) = 254$ and $\mathrm{lcm}(20736,46656) = 362208$.
